# Simplifying $\log_4(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, radicals

> Simplify$$\log_4(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}) .$$

Can we use the following formula to solve it?$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}= \sqrt{\frac{{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}}{2}}$$

Therefore first term will become$$\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}
 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} .$$

$\log_4$ can be written as $\frac{1}{2}\log_2$

Please guide further.

Comment: Your forumal isn't correct, try with $a=b=1$ than lhs is $\sqrt{2}$ and rhs is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Hint : compute $\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^2=2\sqrt{2^2-\sqrt{3}^2}+4=6$

Comment: @Sachin: Did you get the solution to the geometry problem you had posted yesterday?

Comment: @ Inceptio  I have written one comment on your solution please check.. thanks for clarification..

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}$

$x^2=(2+\sqrt 3)+(2-\sqrt 3)+2\sqrt{(2+\sqrt 3)(2-\sqrt 3)}=6$

I think you get it from here.

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you : Jasoncube; inceptio, ramon, dominic.... thanks once again for your nice clarification....

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac{4+2\sqrt3}2}=\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt3)^2+1^2+2\cdot\sqrt3\cdot1}2}=\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt3+1)^2}2}$$

$$\text{So,}\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$\text{Similarly, }\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: There is no "positive root" to consider, $\sqrt{a} \ge 0$ whenever $a \ge 0$. Don't confuse $\sqrt{a}$ with the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 - a = 0$, which are $\pm \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @vonbrand, understood & rectified.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}})=\sqrt k$

Your $k=6$, Now its just $\frac{1}{2} \log_46$